# C# - How to create a KeyValuePair with the result of two foreach loops?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, loops, key-value

So below is the code that I currently have (it doesn't work because the last block sees the arrays an undefined, it's to show what I want to do)

```
IEnumerable<string> sponsorshipQuery1 =
  from runner1 in venueQuery6.Descendants("Runner")
  where (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") > 0
  orderby (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") descending
  select runner1.Element("Firstname").Value;

IEnumerable<string> sponsorshipQuery2 =
  from runner1 in venueQuery6.Descendants("Runner")
  where (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") > 0
  orderby (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") descending
  select runner1.Element("Sponsorship").Value;

string[] nameArray;
string[] moneyArray;

foreach (string name in sponsorshipQuery1)
{
  nameArray = sponsorshipQuery1
    .OfType<object>()
    .Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
}

foreach (string money in sponsorshipQuery2)
{
  moneyArray = sponsorshipQuery2
    .OfType<object>()
    .Select(o => o.ToString())
    .ToArray();
}

Console.WriteLine("All sponsorship money raised in descending order:");
for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.Length; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(nameArray[i] + " has raised £" + moneyArray[i]);
}
```

Ideally, I want to be able to execute the for loop at the bottom. I'd guess at replacing the two foreach loops and making them KeyValuePairs but I don't know how to do that.

I'm also new to using Linq queries so the reason why I have a mixture of query syntax and => syntax is because I was taught the query syntax, but I'm also trying code I've found on the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears from your example code that you can just get both values in one query, and keep them in an anonymous type:

```
var results = from runner1 in venueQuery6.Descendants("Runner")
                  where (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") > 0
                  orderby (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") descending
                  select new { 
                     Name = runner1.Element("Firstname").Value,
                     Amount = runner1.Element("Sponsorship").Value
                  };
```

And then you can loop over these results:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Name + " has raised £" + result.Amount);
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use the `select new` with braces, from what I've learned I'd only selected a single value. This works, thank you!

Comment: @TerminalGuy it *is* a single value, but that single value can contain multitudes :)

Answer (score 2):

The highest-level way of iterating two sequences in tandem is with `Zip`. To get `KeyValuePair`s I'd use

```
sponsorshipQuery1.Zip(sponsorshipQuery2, (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, v))
```

Though I'd likely not use `KeyValuePair` at all, but something more specific to my task or an anonymous type, unless I truly cared about it as a key and value pair.

Iterating two arrays you've already covered. To do a double-`foreach` on two `IEnumerable<T>` that can't (necessarily) be indexed one needs to break down at least one of the loops to its component `MoveNext()` and `Current`

```
using (var en1 = sponsorshipQuery1.GetEnumerator())
{
  foreach(var item2 in sponsorshipQuery2)
  {
    if (!en1.MoveNext())
    {
      break;
    }
    var item1 = en.Current;
    // Do something with the two items here. E.g.
  }
}
```

In your particular example though since you have a common source of:

```
from runner1 in venueQuery6.Descendants("Runner")
  where (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") > 0
  orderby (int)runner1.Element("Sponsorship") descending
```

I'd just `select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(runner1.Element("Firstname").Value, runner.Element("Sponsorship").Value)` to begin with.

Comment: `new KeyValuePair`: you need to specify the `<string, string>` (sadly)

Comment: Very interesting...  have to say that (sadly) when I have multiple enumerables to enumerate manually I normally `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext` on both... I haven't ever thought of mixing the `foreach` + `MoveNext`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the slip, @xanatos, yes `KeyValuePair` could do with a `Create` like `Tuple` has, but then it's abused as a tuple enough as it is.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you showing me how to do a double foreach, I was struggling to figure out how I'd do that earlier.